# Maximally Consistent Sets of formulas

Tags: logic

Let T be a maximally consistent sets of formulas. So T∪{φ} (φ is not in T) is not consistent. My question is: Are both T∪{φ}⊢φ and T∪{φ}⊢ ~φ true?
T∪{φ}⊢φ is easily seen. If T∪{φ}⊢ ~φ true, how to prove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes; by definition of [Maximally consistent](https://planetmath.org/maximallyconsistent), $T \cup \{ \varphi \}$ is *inconsistent*.

Thus, $T \cup \{ \varphi \} \vdash \alpha$, for every formula $\alpha$.

---

Maximal consistency is relative to $\vdash$, the *derivability* relation; thus, the details depend on the proof system used.

In most of them you have a rule/axiom corresponding to [Ex Falso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion#Symbolic_representation): $¬α,α \vdash β$

Comment: but by definition, T is inconsistent iff T⊢α and T⊢~α, for some(NOT every) formula α.

Answer (score 1):

$\neg \phi$ belongs to $T$. Suppose it were not in $T$. Then neither $\phi$ nor $\neg \phi$ would belong to $T$. This implies that $T$ is not maximal, because at least one of the following would be a consistent set which extends $T$: either adding $\phi$ to $T$ or adding its negation to $T$.

This proof still has a hole though: why is it not possible that both $T \cup \{ \phi \}$ and $T \cup \{ \neg \phi \}$ are inconsistent? Hint: consider whether $T \cup \{ \phi \vee \neg \phi \}$ is consistent under the assumption that it is possible.

(Throughout, I've assumed we're working in a two-valued logic.)